# JavaScript: Having trouble returning custom object information

Tags: javascript, object

I've made some new objects with object methods and I'm having trouble returning the information.
I intend for `allPages` to be a 2d array:

```
        var allPages = [[]];

        function textbox(type)
        {
            this.type=type;
            this.getInfo = function () { return ( this.type ); };
        }

        function addTextbox(dropdown)
        {

            var myindex  = dropdown.selectedIndex;
            var SelValue = dropdown.options[myindex].value;

            if(SelValue == "String")
            {

                    var tb = new textbox("string");
                    allPages[allPages.length-1].push(tb);

                    var string = "";
                    for (i = 0;i < allPages.length;i++)
                    {
                        for(j = 0;j < allPages[i].length;j++)
                        {
                            string = string + allPages[i][j].getInfo;
                        }
                    }
                    <!-- Problem here: prints "function () { return this.type; }"-->
                    document.write(string);
                }

            }
}
```

Comment: @epascarello Was just testing, no need for comments like that.

Comment: `console.log` is the way to go. `document.write` does nasty stuff, even when testing. It can change how code runs, same with alerts.

Comment: @epascarello Where does it actually log to?

Comment: What browser? [Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/), [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html), [IE8+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx#consolelogging)

Comment: Did you click the link for Firefox? Gives you the information you need.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, I'm new to web dev so I'm quite unfamilar with the tools. The `console.log` is very useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function, you are referencing it

```
allPages[i][j].getInfo;
```

should be

```
allPages[i][j].getInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks! I realised that just as you posted! xD I hate that.. I'll give you the rep as the first poster.

Answer (score 2):

3 lines above where you state the problems exists, it should be:

```
string = string + allPages[i][j].getInfo(); // mind the () at the end.
```